# output the URL of doc library powershell

Tags: powershell

I have this code :

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://mysite 
ForEach($list in $web.Lists)
{

if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")
{
    Write-Host $list.Fields
    if($list.Fields.ContainsField("marking") -eq $true)
    {
        Write-Host "found" $list.Title
    }
}
}
```

I want it to out put the URL of the document library

Comment: did you try this one $List.DefaultViewUrl?

Comment: can you put that as an answer as that is what I want

Comment: i just post it as anwser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another property of List called DefaultViewURL, try that one.

```
 $List.DefaultViewUrl
```

Here is MSDN Article.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557895(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557895%28v=office.14%29.aspx)